# Show modification dates in portlets

Tags: plone

Our portlets show a title and a creation date. The items are sorted by modification date. When someone modifies the content of an old news item, it will be put on top of the list with the old creation date instead of the current modification date. This is confusing. Is there a way to show the modification date in the portlets? In the Zope management interface or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plone's default portlet templates are all found in ZMI > portal_view_customizations.  Unfortunately, they are not terribly clearly identified...

- News Portlet = news.pt
- Collection Portlet = collection.pt
- Events Portlet = events.pt
- Recent Items portlet = recent.pt
- Review Portlet = review.pt
- Static Text Portlet = static.pt (but this of course doesn't use dates)

Comment: I found it in the Collection Portlet.

Comment: tal:content="python:toLocalizedTime(obj.Date)"  ->  tal:content="python:toLocalizedTime(obj.ModificationDate)"